# Celery retry only the fail request in the loop and continue with the other

Tags: python-3.x, celery, celerybeat

I'm kinda new to celery as a whole and having the problem with retry case on a for loop:

i have the following task:

```
@app.task(bind=True, autoretry_for=(CustomException,), retry_kwargs={'max_retries': 10,'countdown': 30})
def call_to_apis(self):
   api_list = [api1, api2, api3, api4, api5,...]
   for api in api_list:
       try:
           response = requests.get(api)
           if response.status_code == 500:
              raise CustomException
       except CustomException:
           continue
```

From my understanding celery will retry on my `CustomException` get raised.

In the case of retry, will it only retry for the the failed api or will it just run the whole process of every api in the api_list again? If so is there anyway for it to only retry the failed api ?

Expected result: only retry the failed api

**EDIT:**

i have split it into 2 different tasks and 1 request function as follow:

```
@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(300.0, call_to_apis.s())
    print("setup_periodic_tasks")

def call_api(api):
    response = requests.get(api)
    if response.status_code == 500:
        raise CustomException
    elif response.status_code == 404:
        raise CustomWrongLinkException


@app.task(default_retry_delay=30, max_retries=10)
def send_fail_api(api):
    try:
        call_api(api)
    except NonceTooLowException:
        try:
            send_fail_api.retry()
        except MaxRetriesExceededError:
            print("reached max retry number")
            pass
    except Exception:
        pass


@app.task()
def call_to_apis():
   api_list = [api1, api2, api3, api4, api5,...]
   for api in api_list:
       try:
          call_api(api)
       except CustomException:
          send_fail_api.delay(api)
       except CustomWrongLinkException:
          print("wrong link")
       except Exception:
          pass
```

it worked and the other apis get to complete, with failed api it supposed to call to another task and retry for 10 time each delay 30 seconds.

But i'm getting more than expected retries about 24 times(expected to only retry 10 times) and it also printed out `reached max retry number` at 10th retry but it still retry until 24 retries

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The whole task will be retried in case of a known exception (specified in `autoretry_for` decorator argument), see the [documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-retry-for-known-exceptions). Celery can't know by any means the state of the task when exception is raised, that's what you have to handle. I would suggest splitting the task into individual tasks (one per API) and call them separately, presumably creating some [workflow](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#the-primitives).

Comment: i see what you mean it trigger if there an exception in the whole function and rerun the loop again. I had rewrite to turn it into 2 tasks but i'm having problem with number of retries